# How can I fix an Z-Index problem by selecting div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello so I got this output right now:

[image: example]

basically I genereate from an Array dynamicly the Divs which are placed like that.

Now I wanted to press the "hidden" div so that the hidden div gets shown and the first div is smaller than so when I press like item 3 it would something like this:
[image: DesiredOutput]

and for now It kinda works but just when I click item 1 then 2 and then 3 when I press for example item 3 from item 1 I get this Output:
[image: wrongOutput]

I know why it has this behaviour because the Z-Index i set is wrong when I skip an item but I dont know how to fix my js Jquery code so that this "Bug" will no longer appear.

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const items = [
    { picturePath: '../example.png', desc: 'Beschreibung 1', title: 'Titel 1' },
    { picturePath: '../example.png', desc: 'Beschreibung 1', title: 'Titel 2' },
    { picturePath: '../example.png', desc: 'Beschreibung 1', title: 'Titel 3' },
  ];
  const $container = $('#Portfolio-Items');
  let currentMaxZIndex = 100; 

  items.forEach((item, index) => {
    $('<div class="item"></div>')
      .css({
        'z-index': currentMaxZIndex - index, 
        'margin-top': `${20 * index}px`,
        'background-image': `url(${item.picturePath})`
      })
      .appendTo($container);
  });

  $('.item').on('click', function() {
    currentMaxZIndex++; 
    $(this).css('z-index', currentMaxZIndex); 
  });
});
```

```css
#Portfolio-Items {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0px 10px 20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: none;
  background-color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: z-index 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease; 
}
.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="Portfolio" class="section center">
  <div id="Portfolio-Items">

  </div>
</section>
```

so does anyone know how to set up the Z-Index correctly when I skip an item and not cliking the Items in the right order? Because when I click in the right order it works but not when Its in the wrong order.

Comment: You're building a non-intuitive UI which will lead to a bad UX. You should use animations not just swip-swap z-indexes. But even so, by using animations seems like you did not thought out the cards revealing transitions pretty well... Also to anticipate: no, it's not natural to move-animate one card *through* the other in order to bring it on top.

Comment: so u are saying that I should rethink the whole basic design for better UX?

Comment: Yes because it's unnatural to see a physical element ghost-through another element even with animation. See [**this jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/buyoz3js/) I created as example. It's utterly ugly and sign of poor animating skills. First you need to have a clear idea on how you want those cards to move (should be as close as in nature) - than we can talk about implementation in CSS / JS. There's many ways, you need to choose the best one that fits your application requirements and the desired output.